# SQL Statement to grab data from entry form to Data table in Microsoft Access 2010 VBA

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access-2010

So I'm setting up a database in MS Access 2010 (first time doing this). I can't seem to get the syntax of the SQL statement right. I want to take the data I have entered into a data entry form and insert a new row into a table, with that data. All of this using SQL in the VBA editor (only code I have available, all others are blocked)

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
    Dim sSQL As String

    sSQL = "INSERT INTO Data (Type, Name, Quantity, Amount, Class, Series, Client, Date1, Date2) VALUES " & _
            "('" & Me!txtType & "','" & Me!txtName & "'," & Me!txtQuantity & "," & Me!txtAmount & ",'" & Me!txtClass & "','" & Me!txtSeries & "','" & Me!txtClient & "'," & Me!date1 & "," & Me!date2 & ")"
    Debug.Print sSQL

    CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
End Sub
```

So i Get the following error when i run the code, from the VBA editor :

"Run-time error '3134':

Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

And the printout of the SQL statement looks correct :

```
INSERT INTO Data (Type, Name, Quantity, Amount, Class, Series, Client, Date1, Date2)
    VALUES ('Purhcase', 'TV', 500, 100, '', '', ' Bob', 05.08.2019, 05.08.2019)
```

Comment: you need to wrap the dates `05.08.2019` and with quotes as `'05.08.2019'`, especially better to consider as `'2019-08-05'` conforming to ISO standard.

Comment: I have tried putting quotes on too, however I still get the same error. When i put into quotes i even put the format of the data column to text and still get the error. And since the dates come from a Form the format has to be one of the defined ones so i chose _Short Date_

Comment: Btw, do not prefer concatenations for substitution of your paramteres, rather prefer using placeholders, especially against SQL injetions.

Comment: Could you give an example, not sure what you mean. I'm guessing you mean create placeholders for the `'" & Me!txtType & "'` ?

Comment: You can try `CONVERT(date,'05.08.2019',104)` instead of  direct `05.08.2019` in insert statement. because as you mentioned that input format is fixed.

Comment: Didn't change, even if i remove the dates from the form it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer :

turns out one of the names of my data fields was a reserved word, therefore i simply put them all into [] and it solved the issue.

Thanks anyways for the help guys!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593422/vba-run-time-error-3134 like this one - that's great , good luck